# How to compile Go programs in AltLinux?

Tags: golang, altlinux

I have a SimplyLinux version VERSION="9.1 (Destiny)"
And need to compile this sources https://www.aptly.info/download/

git clone https://github.com/aptly-dev/aptly
When I'm trying to do that I getting following error

```
make install
go generate
go install -v
main.go:11:2: package embed is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/golang/src/embed)
make: *** [Makefile:32: install] Error 1
```

Please tell me what is required to compile go programs on Alt/Simply Linux? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this question can help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845013/package-xxx-is-not-in-goroot-when-building-a-go-project

Answer (score 0):

The `embed` package was added [in Go 1.16](https://pkg.go.dev/embed?tab=versions), so you need Go 1.16 or later to build this program.

You might as well [download the latest version of Go](https://go.dev/dl/), it’s backwards-compatible.